# Dynamically give .cluster.local DNS in environment variables in sts

Tags: kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

I want to create an environment variable in the pod created by my sts which would consist of its FQDN.
As the dns domain - ".cluster.local" can be different for various clusters, like '.cluster.abc', or '.cluster.def', I want to populate that dynamically based on the cluster settings.
I checked that .fieldRed.fieldPath doesn't consist of anything like it.

Is there any other option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature of Kubernetes. You would need to use a higher level templating system like Kustomize or Helm.

Comment: Can you please suggest how I can achieve that in Helm? I am using helm charts only.